# Append numpy ndarrays with different dimensions in loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append, multidimensional-array

I need to append the arrays created in each loop so that I get a single ndarray at the end. The code structure is like this:

```
for...:
      .
      .
      .
     for...:
         list1 = array([some_math_here])
         list2.append(list1)

     #each loop creats a list, converting it to array() gives different shaped arrays:
     array(list2).shape
     (2939, 4)
     (2942, 4)
     (2027, 4)
     (2030, 4)

     #list3 collects all the generated results
     list3.append(list2)
```

**Q:**
How can I have an array instead of list3, with `n*4` columns and different number of rows?

I tried by creating an empty array `a = array([0.,1.])` and then `append(a,array(list_2))` but doesn't work. I'm aware of `hstack` `vstack` etc, but cannot make use of them together with `append` in the loop. Any advice how?

**UPDATE**
 Here's the actual code with output from suggested methods:

```
files_ = glob.glob('D:\Test files\*.txt')
tfile_ = loadtxt('times.txt')    
averages_, d = [], []

with open ('outfile.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)

    for fcount_, fname_ in enumerate(files_):   
        data = loadtxt(fname_ , usecols = (1,2,3,4))    
        average_, fcol = [], []
        seg_len = 3

        for x in range(0, len(data[:,0]), seg_len):
            sample_means = [mean(data[x:x+seg_len,i]) for i in range(4)]
            none_zeros = [x if x >= 0 else x == 0 for x in sample_means]            
            average_.append(none_zeros)

        fcol = cumsum(array(average_)[:,0])
        average_ = array([row + [col] for row, col in zip(average_, fcol)])
        averages_.append(average_)
    d = concatenate(array(averages_))    
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    df.to_csv('pdtest2.csv')
```

**output:**

```
           0         1         2         3         4
0   0.037039  0.103792  0.136116  0.579297  0.037039
1   0.051183  0.104669  0.177728  0.593771  0.088222
2   0.059517  0.105437  0.174274  0.571402  0.147739
3   0.053212  0.102476  0.167530  0.645745  0.200950
4   0.054637  0.104450  0.165228  0.596622  0.054637
5   0.051622  0.101161  0.166708  0.595964  0.106259
6   0.057324  0.099077  0.168024  0.596841  0.163583
7   0.054692  0.103573  0.157168  0.598596  0.218275
8   0.066699  0.100612  0.145984  0.591578  0.284974
9   0.120866  5.527104  4.678589  2.401020  0.120866
10  0.113958  5.176220  4.669872  2.361985  0.234824
11  0.121469  4.879613  4.659017  2.359573  0.356293
12  0.122511  4.695618  4.642240  2.363959  0.478803
13  0.126650  4.621933  4.620447  2.347073  0.605453
14  0.132708  4.676868  4.517568  2.364617  0.132708
15  0.125087  4.693535  4.459672  2.381941  0.257795
16  0.132708  4.715246  4.444705  2.334353  0.390503
17  0.133476  4.745619  4.406300  2.317467  0.523979
```

while I want :

```
    0           1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9           10          11          12          13          14          15          16          17          18          19
0   0.037038522 0.103792144 0.136115724 0.57929719  0.037038522 0.054637318 0.104450043 0.16522775  0.596621864 0.054637318 0.12086581  5.527104488 4.678589189 2.401020431 0.12086581  0.132707991 4.67686799  4.517567512 2.364616645 0.132707991
1   0.051183348 0.104669343 0.177727829 0.593770968 0.08822187  0.051621948 0.101160549 0.166708023 0.595963965 0.106259265 0.113957871 5.176219782 4.669871979 2.361985046 0.234823681 0.125087328 4.693534961 4.459672089 2.381941338 0.257795319
2   0.059516735 0.105436892 0.17427386  0.571402402 0.147738605 0.057323738 0.099077202 0.168023821 0.596841163 0.163583003 0.121468884 4.879613015 4.659016582 2.359572747 0.356292565 0.132707991 4.715245885 4.444704808 2.334353258 0.39050331
3   0.05321187  0.102476346 0.167530397 0.645744989 0.200950475 0.054692143 0.103572845 0.157168489 0.598595561 0.218275146 0.122510557 4.695618334 4.642240062 2.363958746 0.478803122 0.13347554  4.745619253 4.406299754 2.317467166 0.52397885
4   0           0           0           0           0           0.066698797 0.1006123   0.145984208 0.591577971 0.284973943 0.126649838 4.621932787 4.620447035 2.347072653 0.60545296  0           0            0          0           0
```

Comment: Is this a valid Python syntax?

Comment: You can't quite get what you're looking for, and what you're looking for probably isn't quite what you want. What do all these something-by-4 arrays represent? Are you sure you don't want to stack these vertically instead of horizontally? And do you really need the `for` loop, or can you use vectorized operations to produce cleaner, faster code without it?

Comment: @user2357112, 'stack vertically' is what I want, and I think when each array has 4 columns, and I said one array with n*4 columns, I meant that, yes? I have been using Python for only 2 weeks now, and surely my code is not he most efficient one, but as it takes several txt files does some math on columns of each, I have the loops.

Comment: As @CT says, you cannot have a non-uniformly shaped array.  To get around this, you can pad the end of the shorter arrays with `np.nan` or `0` or use a masked array.  The method by which to stack though would be to append your arrays to a _list_ through your loop, then call `np.column_stack` or `np.hstack` on your _list_ at the end of the loops, don't `np.append` to the arrays within the loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't create a `n*4` 2d `array` if `n` for each column is different:

```
>>> np.vstack((np.arange(10),np.arange(1,11),np.arange(2,12)))
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> np.vstack((np.arange(10),np.arange(0,11),np.arange(0,12)))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#36>", line 1, in <module>
    np.vstack((np.arange(10),np.arange(0,11),np.arange(0,12)))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 226, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate(map(atleast_2d,tup),0)
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

See the `ValueError`, when the dimension of each `array` is different.

You either has to stay with `list` for `list3` or fill each `list2` to equal length.

For higher dimension, the same rule applies: `np.vstack((np.ones((10,4)),np.ones((10,6)),np.ones((10,6))))` won't work, but `np.vstack((np.ones((10,4)),np.ones((11,4)),np.ones((12,4))))` will and create a 35*4 `array`.

In your case, if you `vstack` your `list2`s, you will get get a 9938*4 `array`, if that is what you want. (I don't get the *different number of rows* part)

EDIT:

To pad the shorter `arrays` so that every `array` has the same `shape`, you need:`np.lib.pad`

```
>>> b=np.random.randint(0,20, size=(12,4))
>>> np.lib.pad(b, ((0,3),(0,0)), 'constant', constant_values=[0.])
array([[ 5,  2, 10,  7],
       [ 7, 17,  8, 11],
       [ 7,  7,  2, 10],
       [16, 17, 15, 16],
       [ 0, 19,  5,  6],
       [18, 19, 18,  6],
       [ 2,  8, 11, 19],
       [ 3, 17, 18, 16],
       [10,  1, 12, 11],
       [ 0,  7,  1, 14],
       [ 7, 17,  8, 16],
       [12,  6,  3,  5],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

`((0,3),(0,0))` means to pad 3 elements in the end of the first axis and pad 0 elements in the beginning of it. Also, it means to pad nothing in the 2nd axis. In your case you need to  `((0,max_length-length_of_current_array),(0,0))`.

Then you just stack them all up using `np.hstack`.

But in my opinion you may want to pad `nan` instead of `0.`. `0.` may be meaningful data value.

Comment: I think what @PyLearner wants is `np.column_stack` (or equivalently in their case, `np.hstack`)  Your answer is correct in that it is impossible to have a uniform array given their inputs, but your example is the transpose of theirs.

Comment: @askewchan, yes, I suspected that is the case. But then I noticed OP's comment ''stack vertically' is what I want'. Anyway, the idea will be the same. Cheers!

Comment: haha, true.  actually I've found the names of all the stack functions can be ambiguous if you don't already know what they do. e.g., `vstack`: stack in vertical direction, or stack vertical things?

Comment: Thanks guys for this. Seems like I git confused with vstack, hstack... What I meant was that the 4 columns created in each loop be stored next to the previous 4 columns. I think this means stacking horizontally rather than vertically!

Comment: en, that's move confusing..., if the `array`s created in the loop have the shape of `(2939, 4)` `(2942, 4)` `(2027, 4)` and `(2030, 4)`, the resulting array should have the shape of `(9938, 4)`? @askewchan, totally agree, it is quite confusing. As much headache `R` has given me, i think `cbind()`, `rbind()` is much more intuitive than `vstack()`, `hstack()` (and `dstack()` of course).

Comment: @CTZhu, Sorry for the confusion. The resulting array will be (2942, 16) and I think the last rows of the shorter columns will be filled with zeros?

Comment: Awesome @CTZhu. Many many thanks for your help mate. As you said using `nan` is better in my case.

Comment: `np.pad` should point to `np.lib.pad`.  And to use `nan` instead of `0.`, just use `np.nan` and be sure your array is of floats (you can't have `np.nan` in an integer array).

Comment: Thanks @askewchan. I found that `np.where` doesn't work for columns with `nan`. But filling shorter columns with `0`s solved the issue!

Comment: Instead of `np.where`, use `np.isfinite` if you want to find values that are not `nan` or `inf`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to make a plain Python list of NumPy arrays.  Each array will have the same column count and types, but perhaps different numbers of rows.  So you should start with simply `list3 = []` and then do `list3.append(arr)` N times.  Then at the end, if you want one big NumPy array with all the rows, just do `np.concatenate(list3)` to put them all together at once.  This is more efficient than trying to concatenate NumPy arrays in the loop.